# Intellij create sample struts web project with java,then show this error

Tags: intellij-idea, struts2

Failed to download 'http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/struts/struts2-core/2.5.14.1/struts2-core-2.5.14.1.jar':
central.maven.org

Comment: Add screenshot showing where and when you see this. But it looks like it is a internet connectivity issue. Check that you can internet access and Maven repository is specified correctly in [Maven settings](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you have URL to Maven Central Repository in your pom.xml defined like:

```
    <repository>
        <id>Maven Central</id>
        <name>Maven Central Repository</name>
        <url>http://central.maven.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
```

then url needs to be updated, to

```
    <repository>
        <id>Maven Central</id>
        <name>Maven Central Repository</name>
        <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
```

because: "Beginning January 15, 2020, The Central Repository will no longer support communication over HTTP" (https://blog.sonatype.com/central-repository-moving-to-https)

Comment: I fixed it. When I create struts project, I will select the first : Use library , click create button , then add all struts libs which downloaded.